# Can I copy text with syntax highlighting

Tags: texstudio, highlighting, syntax, copy-paste

Is there a way to copy LaTeX text out of TeXstudio with syntax highlighting? Will include some macros and small portions of LaTeX in a presentation (Powerpoint) and want to get it as readable as possible.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Most editors don't support copying text including syntax highlighting directly, but I don't know about TeXstudio (if you just google for "export syntax highlighting" you'll find some links to editors that do support it more or less, using some plugins, etc.).  A workaround is, of course, to just do a screen shot.  But see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272885/import-screenshot-into-latex-pdf-blurry/272891#272891) for some problems you might encounter.

Comment: Depending on your syntax highlighting solution, it may be possible to enable copy-pasting syntax-highlighted HTML from the generated PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a simple screen capture with enough zoom can do that, but.... really do you want a copy & paste in PowerPoint?

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Listing Code}
\author{Jhon Doe}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,
numbers=left, numberstyle=\small\sffamily\color{gray}, numbersep=1em,
frame=single, framerule=1pt,
keywordstyle=\color{red!70!black},
commentstyle=\color{blue},
morekeywords={maketitle,apples},
%tabsize=4,
backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!10},
caption=Copy \& Paste from somewhere\ldots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Some \LaTeX\ code}
\begin{lstlisting}{LaTeX}
% This must be before of \maketitle
\title{Listing with syntax}
\author{John Doe}
\date{today} 
% End of preamble
\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\tomatoes % Undefined control sequence
\apples
 ...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Marked it as the answer because I finally decided to search for a good beamer theme for my presentations. Bye bye PowerPoint :).

Answer (score 0):

You can export the source code as formatted HTML (`Tools -> Convert Source To HTML ...`). However, I don't know if PowerPoint can make use of it. If not, you'll probably have to use a screenshot.