# Is there a package for typing examples inside DTX documentation?

Tags: dtx

This is what I see in [pgf](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en) documentation, for example:

[image]

Is there a package, which would help me render similar two-column samples in my own DTX documentation?

I want to type something like this:

```
\begin{sample}
This is \LaTeX!
\end{sample}
```

This should print two columns, with the rendered code on the left and the original TeX on the right (preferably with syntax highlighting).

Comment: There are various ways to do this: I use `listings` for `siunitx`, for example, but `pgf` I think is coded directly. If you want to use the `pgfmanual` style, I'd suggest starting by reading how they do it

Comment: Maybe [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239723/how-can-i-typeset-a-command-and-its-literal-equivalent-in-an-environment) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240317/how-can-i-typeset-an-environment-and-its-literal-equivalent-in-an-environment)

Comment: With respect syntax highlight, an example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273411/can-i-copy-text-with-syntax-highlighting).

Comment: `tcolorbox` package has `listing` and `document` libraries (e.g. using `minted` package) with many options. More generally, see [doc-supp](https://ctan.org/topic/doc-supp) and [syntax highlighting](https://ctan.org/topic/synt-hlt) pages on CTAN.

Comment: Like @Cicada, highly recommend `tcolorbox` and its associated `documentation` library for documenting your code and for typesetting examples. I use it for my own packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made my own package [`docshots`](https://ctan.org/pkg/docshots). This code:

```
\begin{docshot}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
   Hello, {\color{orange}\LaTeX}!
\end{document}
\end{docshot}
```

It renders as such:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using `tcolorbox` and your choice of `listings` or `minted`. There are many, many configuration options available and I haven't attempted to address all of them here. See the `tcolorbox` documentation.

If you use `minted` you need the line at top invoking `--shell-escape` and note that this may be a security risk; use it at your own discretion. You can delete that line if you use `listings`.

Also note that I use TeXShop and its `lualatexmk` engine.

I show `dispExample*` since it is what I use in my own package documentation, but `tcblisting` seems to have more configuration options. It may be the case those same options, or at least a subset thereof, can also be used with `dispExample*` but I have not explored that.

```
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% !TEX parameter = --shell-escape % req. for minted
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
% Choose ONE of the following two lines.
\usepackage[listings,documentation]{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage[minted,documentation]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{dispExample*}{sidebyside}
 Hello, \LaTeX{}!
\end{dispExample*}

% Use this block if you use minted.
%\begin{tcblisting}{listing engine=minted, sidebyside,
%  minted language=latex}
% Hello, \LaTeX{}!
%\end{tcblisting}
%\begin{tcblisting}{listing engine=minted, sidebyside,
%  minted language=latex, text side listing}
% Hello, \LaTeX{}!
%\end{tcblisting}
%\begin{tcblisting}{listing engine=minted, sidebyside,
%  minted language=latex, listing side text}
% Hello, \LaTeX{}!
%\end{tcblisting}

% Use this block if you use listings.
\begin{tcblisting}{listing engine=listings, listing style=tcblatex, sidebyside}
 Hello, \LaTeX{}!
\end{tcblisting}
\begin{tcblisting}{listing engine=listings, listing style=tcblatex, sidebyside, listing side text}
 Hello, \LaTeX{}!
\end{tcblisting}
\begin{tcblisting}{listing engine=listings, listing style=tcblatex, sidebyside, text side listing}
 Hello, \LaTeX{}!
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output from MWE showing results using listings.]