# What are good ways to format source code in LaTeX?

Tags: sourcecode

Criteria for good code formatting:

- Syntax highlighting
- Line numbers
- Code inside should tolerate additional markup (e.g. highlighting salient points)
- Copy/pasting the code from a PDF should Just Work™

With that last point, I would like for whitespace to be preserved so copy/pasting code from the PDF doesn't result in a completely indent-less file.

Comment: You can use [amongst others](https://ctan.org/topic/synt-hlt) `listings` and `minted`. Your last point still is a desideratum, cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472099/how-to-configure-tcblisting-with-minted-to-allow-copy-paste-from-listing-with-wh/472112#472112

Comment: you can use either minted or the listings package. But copy&paste will not "just work". It gets better if you tag the pdf and use lualatex, but it is not reliable. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323354/2388

Comment: Consider [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273430/11604). Here you can copy just the listed code or not depending on the PDF viewer. E.g., in Linux, `atril` or `texworks` viever cannot the take the code without the line numbers, but in `okular` you can select only the framed code without problems.

Comment: For Python, OCaml and C++, you can use the package `piton` (but, as with other packages, copy&paste will note "just work").